# My htaccess RewriteRule works on localhost/mysite but not at mysite.com on a 1&1 shared host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

## Solved:

**unfortunately, the solution is not a satisfying one.  This morning, when trying @Wige's Suggestion, I found, to my suprise, that the Expected values WERE infact sent to the page as a `GET` query.  Apparently, 1&1 (who I know have been making changes to their environment this last couple weeks), did something behind the scenes which magically fixed my problem, and now all of my previously unworking code *is* working as originally expected.**

---

**New info**: The *Apache* version of the production server is **`1.3.34`** vs **`2.2.21`** on my *localhost*.

**I'm having trouble figuring out why my RewriteRule is not working properly in production.**

> `RewriteRule ^page/pretty-url/(.*)$ page.php?query=$1 [L]`

In my local testing environment (`localhost/mysite/page/pretty-url/{...}`) it works fine, but on `mysite.com/page/pretty-url/{...}` it doesn't work properly.  It loads `page.php` as expected but apparently the `?query=$1` piece is ignored (`$_GET` is empty)

I imagine that the problem is somehow related to the server configuration.  I'm on a 1&1 shared hosting account with no httpd.conf access.

---

**What that `RewriteRule` does (or *should* do):**

I want urls like

> *`example.com/page/pretty-url/{{info_for_dynamic_content}}`

to be rewritten to

> *`/page.php?query={{info_for_dynamic_content}}`

So I can access **`info_for_dynamic_content`**

within `php` as `$_GET['query']`

---

**The full .htaccess file for reference:**

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php6 .php

DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php 

Options +FollowSymLinks

# per @Jacques Chester's suggestion
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# the rule in question
RewriteRule ^page/pretty-url/(.*)$ page.php?query=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f 
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]
```

Comment: What version of Apache is running on your localhost vs 1&1?

Comment: If it works in your localhost the problem can't be the mod-rewrite conditions or rules because **they work**, according to your answer. It seems you have it all resolved. ¿Then, what's the question about, finding why your rules don't work in your site? If so, I guess you should just ask that question specifically, making clear it has nothing to do with your rules because they work fine. I think this is a question for `webmasters`. That's only my opinion, but I hope is useful in any way.

Comment: You make a good point.  Before adding the bounty I almost rewrote this to be "what could prevent a RewriteRule which works on one server from working on another." - or something more generalized like that.  I don't think I have the rep to migrate a question - but I think you may be right about that too.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I'll check that out a bit later.  I spent a couple minutes looking (in `phpinfo()`), but wasn't easily able to determine the version.

Comment: `phpinfo()` lists it at the very top or very bottom. Can't remember. It *should* be on there.

Comment: Is the `apache` version within this string?: `Linux infong 2.4 #1 SMP Fri May 18 17:32:59 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux` (the production server)

Comment: To be clear, it sounds like the redirection is working, you are being taken to page.php, and it is only the $_GET that is not working as expected? To verify, if you change the destination to another script, do you get taken to that other script?

Comment: @Wige spot on.  Changing the destination does indeed take you to the other script, yet still no `$_GET` values exposed :-(

Comment: The apache version of the production server is "1.3.34" vs "2.2.21" on my localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your host is storing the variables somewhere else. I would add a call to phpinfo(); into your script and go through the environment variables there to see if you can find the values that should have been in get.

Comment: Here, have some points, lol.  1&1 apparently solved my problem, but they sure as heck ain't gettin my bounty.  I'm voting to close my question as too localized.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be connected to 1&1's hosting environment.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681959/1and1-mod-rewrite-issues), in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856274/599240).

Basically it appears that 1&1 enable "MultiViews". By adding

```
Options -MultiViews
```

You disable that setting for your website and according to various reports, this resolves the issue.

Comment: I tried this quickly last night, and it didn't seem to fix my issue... but I only had a few minutes to play with it, and won't be able to attack it until later today.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with RewriteRule issues on a 1&1 / 1and1 / IONOS shared server for WEEKS and eventually I found the perfect setup for a 1 and 1 shared server, start your .htaccess file like this

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

I hope this helps someone as 1&1 are useless when it comes to htaccess support